# Why Python runs the code outside of __main__ every time?

Tags: python

I'm just wondering the behaviour of Python and how it really works. I have a script to run and collect all followers and friends of an account.

This is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pymongo
import tweepy

from pymongo import MongoClient

from sweepy.get_config import get_config

config = get_config()

consumer_key = config.get('PROCESS_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY')
consumer_secret = config.get('PROCESS_TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET')
access_token = config.get('PROCESS_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN')
access_token_secret = config.get('PROCESS_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')

MONGO_URL = config.get('MONGO_URL')
MONGO_PORT = config.get('MONGO_PORT')
MONGO_USERNAME = config.get('MONGO_USERNAME')
MONGO_PASSWORD = config.get('MONGO_PASSWORD')

client = MongoClient(MONGO_URL, int(MONGO_PORT))

print 'Establishing Tweepy connection'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, retry_count=3)

db = client.tweets
db.authenticate(MONGO_USERNAME, MONGO_PASSWORD)

raw_tweets = db.raw_tweets
users = db.users

def is_user_in_db(screen_name):
    return get_user_from_db(screen_name) is None

def get_user_from_db(screen_name):
    return users.find_one({'screen_name' : screen_name})

def get_user_from_twitter(user_id):
    return api.get_user(user_id)

def get_followers(screen_name):
    users = []
    for i, page in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id=screen_name, count=200).pages()):
        print 'Getting page {} for followers'.format(i)
        users += page
    return users

def get_friends(screen_name):
    users = []
    for i, page in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, id=screen_name, count=200).pages()):
        print 'Getting page {} for friends'.format(i)
        users += page
    return users

def get_followers_ids(screen_name):
    ids = []
    for i, page in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=screen_name, count=5000).pages()):
        print 'Getting page {} for followers ids'.format(i)
        ids += page

    return ids

def get_friends_ids(screen_name):
    ids = []
    for i, page in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_ids, id=screen_name, count=5000).pages()):
        print 'Getting page {} for friends ids'.format(i)
        ids += page
    return ids

def process_user(user):
    screen_name = user['screen_name']

    print 'Processing user : {}'.format(screen_name)

    if is_user_in_db(screen_name):
        user['followers_ids'] = get_followers_ids(screen_name)
        user['friends_ids'] = get_friends_ids(screen_name)

        users.insert_one(user)
    else:
        print '{} exists!'.format(screen_name)

    print 'End processing user : {}'.format(screen_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for doc in raw_tweets.find({'processed' : {'$exists': False}}):
        print 'Start processing'
        try:
            process_user(doc['user'])
        except KeyError:
            pass

        try:
            process_user(doc['retweeted_status']['user'])
        except KeyError:
            pass

        raw_tweets.update_one({'_id': doc['_id']}, {'$set':{'processed':True}})
```

What I keep getting from the log is

```
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 889
Establishing Tweepy connection
Start processing
Processing user : littleaddy80
Establishing Tweepy connection
Start processing
Processing user : littleaddy80
Establishing Tweepy connection
Start processing
Processing user : littleaddy80
Establishing Tweepy connection
Start processing
Processing user : littleaddy80
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 891
```

I'm wondering because `Establishing Tweepy connection` is outside of `__main__` and it shouldn't be running over and over again. I'm just wondering why Python behaves like that or there's a bug in my code?

Comment: Python runs _everything_ in the file, line by line, that's the point of the `__main__` guard.

Comment: It looks more like your script is exiting and being restarted by something; "Establishing Tweepy connection" should only be printed once, regardless of whether the module is imported or executed as a script.

Comment: @chepner I use supervisor to manage the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run/import a python script every statement in it is executed (however when imported this will only happen first time the module is imported or when you do `reload(module)`). There are a few normally present statements that could be noted:

- The execution of function definition means that the function is being defined (not executing the body of the function).
- The execution of an import statement will import the module.
- The execution of a class definition implies that the body of it is executed, mostly it will contain function definitions so it's mostly defining functions.
- The execution of if statements means that the controlling expression is first evaluated and depending on that the body may be executed.
- The execution of assignments means that the rhs-expression will be evaluated with possible side effects.

This is why one normally don't put code directly in the top level of a python script - it will be executed. If it should work as both a script and a module - the code that should be run when running as a script should be enclosed in a `if __name__ == '__main__'`-statement.

Unless you need global variabes your script would be a bunch of function definitions and class definitions followed by:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     code_to_be_executed_iff_run_as_a_script()
else:
     code_to_be_executed_iff_imported()
```

if you need global variables you will have to take special care sometimes to avoid side effects when running/importing the module.

Answer (score 2):

If you want code that runs *only* when imported, it would go in the `else` clause of the normal `__main__` guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Run as a script")
else:
    print("Imported as a module")
```

Comment: If I want to make the connection with Tweep once and share the connection with all the functions inside the script. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly th reason why there's

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Before this condition you should have functions and classes definitions and after it, code you would like to run.

Reason for this is that the `__name__` variable is different when your file is imported (as every python file is also importable module) and run e.g. `python myfile.py`.

Create file e.g. `myfile.py`:

```
# content of myfile.py
print(__name__)
```

When you run it it will print `__main__`.

```
$ python myfile.py 
__main__
```

But during import it carries the name of the imported module (`myfile`).

```
$ python
>>> import myfile
myfile
```